# Using Reshape to build a wide matrix from a table of stacked time series

Tags: r

My original data is a table of stacked time-series. Each row records the weekly sales for a particular store and department pair.

An example with 3 unique store-dept pairings:

```
  Store   Dept     Date      Weekly_Sales  
 ------- ------ ----------- -------------- 
      1      1   5/2/2010               1  
      1      1   12/2/2010              2  
      1      1   19/2/2010              3  
      1      2   5/2/2010               4  
      1      2   12/2/2010              5  
      1      2   19/2/2010              6  
      2      1   5/2/2010               7  
      2      1   12/2/2010              8  
      2      1   19/2/2010              9
```

I wish to use the melt and cast methods under the Reshape2 package to transform my table into this format.

```
    Date      Store1_Dept1   Store1_Dept2   Store2_Dept1  
 ----------- -------------- -------------- -------------- 
  5/2/2010               1              4              7  
  12/2/2010              2              5              8  
  19/2/2010              3              6              9
```

I have 2 questions to seek help with:

1. My approach is to melt my original data frame with Date as my id.

   melt.df <- melt.data.frame(df, id.vars='Date')

This approach yields an error, which I do not understand.

> Error in as.Date.numeric(value) : 'origin' must be supplied

2. I am unsure of how to phrase the formula when using the dcast() method to achieve the result that I need.

Comment: @akrun: Thank you for directing me to a similar question here.

I tried using the same approach for my example:

`library(data.table)`
`dcast(train, Date~Weekly_Sales,value.var = c("Store","Dept"), sep=".")` 
But I received this error:

`Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : subscript out of bounds`

Comment: What you need is `dcast(train, Date ~ Store + Dept, value.var = "Weekly_Sales")`

Comment: @akrun: Thank you, your code worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dcast` from `reshape2`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(train, Date ~ Store + Dept, value.var = "Weekly_Sales")
```